# Expressing current time with natural language

Tags: python, datetime

```
def current_time():
    '''Returns a tuple containing (hour, minute) for current local time.'''
    import time
    local_time = time.localtime(time.time())
    return (local_time.tm_hour, local_time.tm_min)



(hour,minute) = current_time()



def ishtime(hour, minute):
    import random

    Starting_str = ['it is','its',"it's","Current time is"]

    h_str = ['one','two','three','four','five','six','seven','eight','nine','ten','eleven','twelve']

    mid_str = ['almost','nearly','roughly','maybe']

    Ex = ['Exactly' , 'Perpectly' ,'']

    m_str = ['ten','twenty','thirty','fourty','fifty']

    End_str = ['in the morning','in the afternoon','in the evening','at night']

## - define random strings

    Head = Starting_str[int(random.random()*4)]

    Mid = mid_str[int(random.random()*4)]

    Hour = h_str[(int(hour)-1)%12]

    if round(int(minute),-1) == 0 or round(int(minute),-1) == 60:
        Rand_m_str = ''
    else:
        Rand_m_str = m_str[int((round(int(minute),-1)/10))-1]

## -define for final ex)its , it's , almost, one two three..


    if int(hour)>=6 and int(hour)<13:
        Ending = End_str[0]

    elif int(hour)>=13 and int(hour)<19:
        Ending = End_str[1]

    elif int(hour)>=19 and int(hour)<=23:
        Ending = End_str[2]

    elif int(hour)>=0 and int(hour)<6:
        Ending = End_str[3]

## - define 'ending str' ex) in the morning



    if minute == 0 or minute == 00:
        Result = "%s %s 'o clock %s" %(Head,Hour,Ending)

    elif minute%10 == 0:
        Result = "%s %s %s after %s %s" %(Head,Ex[int(random.random()*4)],Rand_m_str,Hour,Ending)

    elif round(int(minute),-1) == 0 or round(int(minute),-1) == 60:
        Result = "%s %s %s%s %s" %(Head,Mid,Rand_m_str,Hour,Ending)

    else:
        Result = "%s %s %s minute after %s %s" %(Head,Mid,Rand_m_str,Hour,Ending)

    return Result

print ishtime(hour,minute)
```

I did this job.. how could i make it simpler?

Comment: You could start by removing "its" and fixing "Perpectly" and capitalization.

Comment: Why not the builtin `datetime.datetime.strftime`?

Answer (score 3):

Python supports double-ended inequalities:

```
End_str = ['at night', 'in the morning','in the afternoon','in the evening']

if 0 <= hour < 6:
    Ending = End_str[0]
elif 6 <= hour < 13:
    Ending = End_str[1]
elif 13 <= hour < 19:
    Ending = End_str[2]
elif 19 <= hour < 24:
    Ending = End_str[3]
```

I've changed 23 to 24 for consistency and rearranged the members of `End_str`.  I don't see how `hour` should be anything other than an integer, so I've removed the casts.

`if minute == 0 or minute == 00` is redundant, since 00 is exactly the same as 0.

I would expect noon and midnight to be handled as special cases.

Answer (score 2):

Avoid constructs like `Ex[int(random.random()*4)]` which are brittle at several levels:

- What if `Ex` is changed to no longer contain 4 elements?
- Hey, it already only has 3 elements.
- Fixing that by using `len(Ex)` is still quite verbose.

Prefer [`random.choice`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/random.html?highlight=random#random.choice), using it like this: `random.choice(Ex)`